# Questions to answer before proposing to use a new language?

Tags: clojure

What are the technical questions I simply must have answers for before I approach someone about introducing a new language?

I'm looking for the list of technical questions that without a really good answer, I should not even waste anyone's time by proposing that we use language X.

PS: (def X clojure)

Comment: Like you want to learn French, or something?

Comment: The title is misleading. It sounds like you want to WRITE a language. You may want to reword.

Comment: I think you're basically asking the same question this person did: "I'm wondering how can a programmer help make sure the right programming language is chosen for a project." http://stackoverflow.com/questions/498650/how-managers-choose-programming-languages

Comment: gnovice this question is much more specific than that. I'm not looking for advice on persuading managers. I'm looking for a technical checklist of things that must be known about a language.

Comment: @Arthur: In that case, your question is still too vague since it will almost certainly depend on what the potential application of the language will be.

Answer (score 17, accepted):

Productivity with a language is neither the only factor, nor a simple scalar in itself.  Important questions include:

- How easy is it to learn the language, if it's not already familiar to people on the team?
- How easy is it to become expert at the language?
- Does the team have access to one or more language experts who have the bandwidth to do the necessary mentoring?
- Are good learning materials (books, blogs, tutorials) and support channels (fora, IRC, mailing lists) available?
- Does the language (or some framework in that language) allow a competent programmer to write the software faster than what you're using now?
- How maintainable is the language?  How readable is the syntax to a competent programmer encountering someone else's code for the first time?  (Think of APL and Perl.)
- Is the language somehow better applicable to your problem domain than what you're using now (e.g., functional languages for distributed computing)?
- How well does the language/platform meet business needs not related to development speed (e.g., performance, scalability)?
- What are the available tools like, and what do they cost?  Is there a debugger available?  An IDE?  Refactoring and unit test support built into the IDE?  Build management and deployment tools?

Comment: +1, lots of good points though I would definitely add library support / strength of open source ecosystem. I've found that is more important than anything else if you actually want to get things done rather than admire the theoretical beauty of your language....

Answer (score 52):

#### A crash course in politics for engineers...

Despite all the mission-statement baloney meant to sound noble and emphasize community support, the real purpose of every business is *return on investment* or, equivalently, *maximizing shareholder value*. If it's a government agency, it's kind of still the same question but the legal owners will have no direct influence and instead you will have proxy owners, such as higher agencies or powerful individual officials.

Decisions, however, are almost always made by *agents*, and so the *[principal-agent problem](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Principal-agent_problem)* (also called the *agency dilemma*) appears; the agents (the management) will make a decision in their interest, and not necessarily according to the shareholder's interest as is theoretically required. In a government agency this is almost 100% of the consideration.

Sadly, this stirs in all the Dilbert and Parkinson's Law complexities.

The best you can conclude is that decisions will be justified on the basis of risk, cost, and benefit, but will tend to be made on the basis of what credit and blame is in store for the agent and understood by the agent, which is a narrow risk consideration of questionable value to the principal but at least an identifiable one.

So, we should now apply this to the language question.  Your manager is likely to avoid threats, risks, scandals, and controversies. His application of the principals's concerns will be mainly through the constraints of budgets and expectations. Here are some examples that should be mostly self-explanatory.

*If you want to use Java or PHP:*

- Everyone is doing it this way
- This is the industry-standard approach for this type of problem
- This is the low-risk approach
- Similar systems have been done many times in Java/PHP

(That's the "no one ever got fired for buying IBM" argument.)

*If you want to use Ruby:*

- Ruby is in the Tiobe top-ten (not quite an industry standard, so this is the best you can do)
- PHP and Java are higher-cost technologies (he probably has a budget as an attempt to mitigate the principal-agent problem)
- PHP and Java are going to be out of fashion "soon" (maybe not, but phrased as a "risk of appearing to stupidly use old tech', and implying the lack of later credit and recognition)
- Ruby is an advanced language with powerful abstractions for cost-effective development (a weak argument for the agent, but offers the possibility of credit. The least effective of all the arguments.)

*If you want to use Clojure:*

- You better prototype the system on weekends and evenings and present it as a solved problem.
- Emphasize parallel Java / Clojure development ("if necessary the entire system can be written in <strike>Clojure</strike> Java")
- Make all the Java arguments and then say something about "the best of both worlds"

Comment: not sure how tongue-in-cheek this is, but it's a great answer.

Comment: "I would like to use a java library called "clojure" to help mitigate concurrent risk"

Comment: @Arthur: ok, that's pure genius

Answer (score 3):

So much depends on what you're currently using, what you're switching to and why that it's difficult to answer. But these are always important:

- What can I do if I choose a new language that I could not do before?
- What could I do faster than I can currently with the new language?
- How will the rest of the team cope with the introduction of the new language?
- If I left, could someone else new to the language pick up where I left off without too many problems?

Answer (score 3):

**What is the business case?**

It comes down to ROI (Return On Investment).

It is not only about an individual's productivity but:

- the whole team
- impact on product lifecycle
- maintainability

etc.

Answer (score 3):

**How easy is it to pick up?** I find this is not that important.

**Does it have IDE support?** Pretty important, but you can work without it.

**Is there a debugger available?** I think this is the most important question I would ask. Once you have a working debugger, you can usually get anything done.

Comment: anything else about the project/programming infrastructure you would recommend?

Answer (score 3):

We hired a team this year and decided to use **Clojure** as our weapon of choice.  The team's background was primarily Java-based but also a wide variety of other languages for hobby work.

The criteria we considered were:

- Can we leverage the Java/JVM background of the team and integrate with an existing Java-based product?
- Can we achieve performance on par with Java?
- Can we build thread-safe concurrent *maintainable* programs?
- Can we leverage a higher level of abstraction
- Can we hire/train people to work in the language?
- Can we maintain a large codebase in the language?
- Are sufficient tools available to work effectively in the language?
- Is there an active community of people growing the language and libs?

We seriously considered Groovy, Scala, and Clojure.  I really enjoy Groovy for lightweight apps but I had serious questions about performance.  Scala and Clojure both have lots to offer on all of the points above.  In the end, our problem domain involves a lot of symbolic manipulation and we felt that Clojure would be a better match but I suspect Scala also would work well.

Answer (score 2):

What will your new language offer that an existing language doesn't already?

We have languages that do just about everything in every way today.  So before introducing a new language, make sure there isn't one already existing that does everything your new language does.  And make sure you know exactly what features your new language will offer that aren't offered in the same combination or at all by other languages.

Unless of course you're just doing this for your own education - in which case forget this question and have at it!

Comment: I'm not proposing writing a new language. I'm talking about introducing a new one to the workplace.

Comment: Ahh, well that is something completely different.  Sorry, I misunderstood the question.

Answer (score 2):

**How will this improve my productivity?**

If this cannot be answered pack up and go home.

Answer (score 2):

**What's the point? / Why?**

**How will it make my job easier?**

Comment: Beacuse he cares? Because he would like to use modern tools and advancement at work, instead in free time? Because he doesn't want to allow the job to make his skills obsolete in a year or two?

Answer (score 2):

Q1: Can I hire people with these skills?

Q2: When I call our outsourcing partner account managers, and ask how much would a typical fixed-cost project cost, if done in the usual way, or done using language X, is the multiplier more than 1?

Q3: Does everyone else in my department also have a favorite language that does about the same job as my favorite language, and should their favorite languages be used as well? What are the practical consequences of this?

Answer (score 0):

A good question to ask is what is the size of the community around the language/framework.  For instance, ruby/rails has a significant community around it, which would make me more comfortable that I would not be "the first kid on the block" to have to deal with a particular problem.

Answer (score 0):

Why limit yourself to one language? Figure out which problems are solved best by which language and offer up services. If the bandwidth between the services is too high, then migrate the problematic services together based on which language solves both best.